# MSDeploy - revert website deployment

Tags: msdeploy, webdeploy

I'm deploying website to IIS using MS Deploy aka Web Deploy (`-verb:sync`) and this is working fine.

However is it possible to completly revert deployment (remove deployed website) using just MS Deploy?

I know that MS Deploy handles updates well but I want to just remove website completely - undoing all changes made by MS Deploy.

Comment: Do you just want to remove the site that was deployed completely, or do you actually need to revert a site back to it's previous state before it was updated with MS Deploy?

Comment: There is no previous state. The site was/is/will be deployed with MS Deploy originally. It's fine to remove it completely.

Answer (score 2):

In short; no.

MSDeploy can sync a given state to your remote IIS by comparing the files (like rsync). It leaves no undo state on the remote server to undo this proces afterwards. The only way to revert it afterwards is by executing msdeploy again but with the original files thus rsyncing the remote server back to the pre-deploy state.

Comment: "It has no markers to undo this proces afterwards unless you provide it with the original deployed files and again upload those using -verb:sync" Doesn't make sense.

Comment: I edited my original anwser, hope it is more clear now.

Comment: So is it possible to backup site using MSDeploy and then deploy from this backup when you want to revert? How would you do that?

Comment: Yes you could before deploying create a package of the current state, deploy and optionally revert by using the just-created backup package http://serverfault.com/questions/296599/is-it-possible-to-create-a-remote-backup-of-a-site-with-msdeploy

Answer (score 1):

You can use the -verb:delete specifying the destination information you used when doing -verb:sync to remove the website.